# EventListener mousemove other elements create issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I have problem with mousemove eventlistener

```
<div id="banner">
<img class="balon1" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/page/obiekt2.png"/>
<img class="balon2" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/page/obiekt1.png"/>
<img class="balon3" src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/img/page/obiekt3.png"/>
   <div class="row h-100" style="position: relative; z-index:300; pointer-events: all;">
       <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
           <h1 style="font-size:60px;">LOREM IPSUM<br/>
                DOLOR SIT<br/>
                AMET GRAVIDA</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 align-self-center">
               <p class="g-pt-50">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam non mauris at ex fringilla interdum. Nullam dignissim erat venenatis ex molestie, id viverra augue dictum. Duis congue laoreet finibus.</p>
               <a href="" class="white-button">Zobacz ofertę</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
   .h-100{
     height:100%;
   }
    #banner{
        position: relative;
        min-height:600px;
        height:calc(100vh - 340px);
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
#banner .balon1{
        position: absolute;
        top:5%;
        right:45%;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index:10;
        transition: 1.5s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation: balon1 10s infinite;
    }
    #banner .balon2{
        position: absolute;
        top:30%;
        right:51%;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index:150;
        transition: 1s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation: balon2 10s infinite;
    }
    #banner .balon3{
        position: absolute;
        top:10%;
        right:5%;
        pointer-events: none;
        z-index:200;
        transition: 0.8s;
        transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        animation: balon3 10s infinite;
    }
</style>

<script>
const balon3 = document.querySelector(".balon3");
const balon2 = document.querySelector(".balon2");
const balon1 = document.querySelector(".balon1");

window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(event){
  balon3.style.transform = "translate(" + -event.offsetX / 20 + "px ," + -event.offsetY / 10 + "px)";
  balon2.style.transform = "translate(" + -event.offsetX / 26 + "px ," + -event.offsetY / 13 + "px)";
  balon1.style.transform = "translate(" + -event.offsetX / 32 + "px ," + -event.offsetY / 16 + "px)";
});
</script>
```

This makes those 3 elements balon1 balon2 and balon3 to move away a little bit away from the mouse.

Everything worked fine when I was adding to elements that had class .balon1, .balon2 and .balon3 with style `pointer-events:none` because mouse cursor was ignoring those elements.

But when I added elements with text and buttons it started to create problems

When I hover to any `<div>` with something inside of it, it starts to make it working weird, those 3 elements move to the left and right, left and right something like shake effect.

And when hovering on any `<a href>` it makes eventlistener mousemowe to stop working.

Any idea how to make this event work proberly always, without adding `pointer-events:none` to all elements and `z-index:-#` ?

Comment: need more code from your project, including html markup

Comment: Added more code with html and style

Comment: it is working OK for me, I'm using Google Chrome.
I also tried to hover over the link and it didn't stopped working.
Which browser are you using? try chrome and also try incognito mode
https://codepen.io/nutak/pen/rNywXeJ

Comment: I think I found the issue but still no fix to that.
When you hover on a button, they get back to their original position and the button is their new are where it reads mouse position...

Comment: Already found the solution, answer at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found the solution!

instead of using `event.offsetX` and `event.offsetY`, just chenge it to  `event.clientX` and `event.clientY`